# What is this classical piece played in Andrew Graham-Dixon's "Renaissance" episode 4?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

*Renaissance* is a six-part documentary series by [Andrew Graham-Dixon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Graham-Dixon)  on Renaissance art. I came across an upload of [episode 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oquO2VLFt3A) on YouTube, and there is a classical piece that starts playing in the background at [21:18](https://youtu.be/oquO2VLFt3A?t=1278).

Can anyone identify it?

Comment: The description below the video lists four titles that were used. _Light in Darkness_ by Evelyn Glennie; _Hymn Of Joy_ - De Wolfe Music; _FUNERAL OF AMENHOTEP III from ACT I, SCENE I OF AKHNATEN_ by the Stuttgart State Opera; _African Sanctus: Agnus Dei - Kyrie_ by David Fanshawe, The Ambrosian Singers, Alan Parker, Mustapha Tettey Addy. Did you check already, whether it's one of those?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4nyWW-ilqM

Answer (score 2):

This piece is an ode by [Henry Purcell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Purcell) titled "Here the deities approve".
You can [listen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4nyWW-ilqM) to a performance of this ode by [Alfred Deller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_Deller), along with [Gustav Leonhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Leonhardt) and the [Leonhardt Baroque Ensemble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonhardt-Consort).

(identified by @YourUncleBob)